# Inserting values into mysql table using jdbc - java application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to implement a user registration using java and it always returns an error, my user login works fine. But why is this error?

I have implemented a register class which creates the connection and inserts the values. The input validation in done in the actionperformed class.

```
   private boolean register(String username,String email,String password) {
   try{           
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
   Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/erp?" + "user=root&password=");     
   PreparedStatement sql = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("Insert into user(username,email,password) values(? , ?, ?)");
   sql.setString(1, username);
   sql.setString(2, email);
   sql.setString(3, password);
   ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery();                        
   if(rs.next())            
       return true;    
   else
       return false;            
   }
   catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   return false;
   }       



private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(jTextField1.getText().length()==0)  // Checking for empty field
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert Username");
    else if(jTextField2.getText().length()==0)  // Checking for empty field
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert E-mail address");
    else if(jPasswordField1.getText().length()==0)  // Checking for empty field
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert Password");
    else if(jPasswordField2.getText().length()==0)  // Checking for empty field
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Re-enter Password");
    else if(!jPasswordField1.getText().equals(jPasswordField2.getText()))  // Checking for equal passwords
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password fields do not match");
    else{
        String user = jTextField1.getText();   // Collecting the input
        String email = jTextField2.getText(); // Collecting the input
        String pwd = jPasswordField1.getText(); // Collecting the input
            //String pwd = pass;  // converting from array to string
    if(register(user,email,pwd))
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered Successfully");        
    else
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");

    }        
}
```

Comment: Can you put error stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem because you use `PreparedStatement executeQuery` method. But this method is good for querying database. And for updating database you have to use 
`PreparedStatement updateQuery` method. 
Short example:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
        + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong");
preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
// execute insert SQL stetement
preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

in this question your are mention what type of error you are getting

what ever it should be you just use debugger it will help you to resolve the bug

Answer (score 0):

method executeQuery() is used to retrieve data from DB, like "Select" query/statements but if you want to run "update" ,"delete" or "insert" queries you have to use executeUpdate().use

`ResultSet rs = sql.executeUpdate();`